# SVG drawing didn't work

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I made small script to drawing SVG polygons, here is example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGEQwV

```
var refreshDuration = 10000;
var refreshTimeout;
var numPointsX;
var numPointsY;
var unitWidth;
var unitHeight;
var points;

function onLoad() {
  var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
  svg.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
  svg.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
  document.querySelector('#bg').appendChild(svg);

        var polygon = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'polygon');
            polygon.setAttribute('points', '-5.1 ,-7.1 343.4,-7.1 386.7,194');
        polygon.setAttribute('fill', '#000');
        svg.appendChild(polygon);
      }
```

But this code didn't work :( What did I do wrong ?

Comment: What went wrong? You should provide more detail in your question so that we may help you accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code for creating the polygon is completely fine, but it will not draw it unless you call "onLoad".
if you will be calling it multiple times, you will also need to clear the innerHTML of your div "bg".